# How to send html format email using php in google application engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am using a `php` application on `google application engine` to send `emails` but whenever I check the actual email received it does not have any formatting or styling even though i added some `html` in there . I get back the tags and all. I would like to add my own html styling to the email. The code I am using is:

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php';
use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

$mail_options = [
    "sender" => 'myaccount@gmail.com',
    "to" => $toaddr,
    "subject" => $subj,
    "textBody" => $msg,
        ];
try 
{
$message = new Message($mail_options);
$message->send();
echo '<h1>success</h1>';
} 
catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) 
{
echo $e;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/) there is an option field htmlBody so you can add to it to your code

```
$mail_options = [
    "sender" => 'myaccount@gmail.com',
    "to" => $toaddr,
    "subject" => $subj,
    "textBody" => $msg,
    "htmlBody" => $html_formatted_msg,
];
```

Note: I am using the Python runtime, which works in the same way, I haven't try this in php.

Answer (score 0):

Your mail function should be like this:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

With the $headers variable like this:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

(The $headers variable should be defined before the mail function)

Hope it works.

Comment: I can't seem to get the code to accept this. Keep giving me error

Comment: The php mail() function is disabled in app engine. You need to use their (or another) API to send mail instead.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following before `$message->send();`

```
$message->isHTML(true);
```

And please refer this link, if it doen't work,

> http://ctrlq.org/code/19589-send-mail-php

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work. Do you have another suggestion? I am now getting a internal server error 500.

Comment: This is irrelevant, it refers on how to send mails from Gmail as the title of the article states, not Google App Engine.